Export imported word file using REST make the file corrupted
Update: Updated the problem to reflect recent learnings and make it more clear.
I have a scenario where I need to import a file from OpenText (OT) to ServiceNow and then export it back to OpenText (kind of moving the file which is not possible locally) using REST. We are talking about word/.docx files. I am not in control of the OT side so I need to solve this problem on my end in ServiceNow.
I want to take the response body and add it to the multipart when exporting it back to OT in the same format as when receiving it. This is not happening when just putting the response body to the multipart to export back to OT, the file gets corrupted. Not sure what is happening when javascript put the content in a string and then put the content back into the multipart. Server side javascript in ServiceNow doesn't support Node.js, classes like File or FileReader so I cannot get hold of the stream, just the response body, with file content, as a string.
We managed to get this to work using powershell in an attempt to isolate what the problem can be. Hence, the problem is on the ServiceNow side, not the OT side.
What is the solution to get this import and export working in ServiceNow?

ServiceNow version: Washington patch 8
Javascript version: ES5

Example of request. This is ServiceNow specific and there doesn't seem to be any other way of make a REST request to third party from within a script:
var r2 = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2(<REST Message>, <Method>);
r2.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--xxx');
var boundary = '--xxx';
var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file.docx"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document\r\n\r\n' + fileContentStr + '\r\n' + '--' + boundary + '--';
r2.setRequestBody(body);
var response2 = r2.execute();
var responseBody = response2.getBody();

I tried a few things while I was thinking it may be an encoding issue:
One attempt:
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < responseBody.length; i++) {
       var charCode = responseBody.charCodeAt(i);
       result.push(charmap[charCode] || charCode);
}
fileContentStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result);

Another attempt:
var fileBytes = responseBody.getBytes('ISO-8859-15'); //ISO 8859-15
    
var fileContentStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < fileBytes.length; i++) {
       fileContentStr += String.fromCharCode(fileBytes[i]);
}

Yet another attempt:
var fileBytes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < responseBody.length; i++) {
      fileBytes.push(responseBody.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
}
fileContentStr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, fileBytes);

Quite a few other attempts where classes isn't available on server side.

It's not obvious, at least to me, why you need to do anything to the file at the ServiceNow end. It seems that you're taking a file from OT and then pushing it back to OT. Why do you need to do anything to it at all? Can't you just treat the file as an anonymous blob of binary data so long as you use the same content type header when pushing it back that was in the request when receiving the file? Or do you need some data contained within the word document?

I have of course tried posting it back using .getBody of the response and it doesn’t work, file gets corrupted. I start to understand the problem actually is ServiceNow specific. There is no way getting hold of the stream. I do need to use the ServiceNow classes that don’t provide such possibilities but only returns the body as a string using .getBody of the response.

@phuzi Updated my question to reflect your comment.

"Not sure what is happening when javascript put the content in a string" I think this is your problem. The content is not a string and should not be be treated as such and why it is getting corrupted. A word document (.docx), as you have correctly stated, is essentially zip file and needs to be treated as binary data.

I'm not familiar with ServiceNow. Which version of ServiceNow are you using and what versions of JavaScript does it support? Please add this information to the question.

Updated. I suspect it is not a bug but ServiceNow is just lacking the necessary classes/methods.

Are you using Fetch or XMLHttpRequest to retrieve data from OT? Could you include the code used to fetch the document from OT (Do not include any sensitive information). Trying to remember what is not available in ES5. Or is it a different API

It is server side, XMLHttpRequest is not available as I understand it. And I can't instantiate it when trying. I will look into fetch if that is something available.

Add the request. The request in ServiceNow is partly configuration (REST Message/Method) and scripting.
